# Следует ли обращаться к участникам по имени в вопросах на Мете?

Tags: поддержка, faq

Я наблюдаю, что один из участников не до конца понимает правила сообщества, либо намеренно их игнорирует. Каким образом я могу поднять вопрос на Мете так, чтобы обсудить конкретное нежелательное поведение? Следует ли предоставлять контекст проблемы в явном виде?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/289913/274323) [@animuson](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/141525/animuson)</sub>

### Сосредоточьтесь на проблеме, а не на участнике.

Мы удаляем метку [какой-то-участник](/questions/tagged/%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba) каждый раз, когда она появляется. Акцентирование внимания в вопросе на Мете на конкретном участнике почти *всегда* приводит к неприятным последствиям. Да, иногда очень сложно поднять вопрос, не упоминая конкретного участника, но вы должны приложить все возможные усилия, чтобы в вопросах не фигурировали ссылки на учетные записи. Пожалуйста, просто опишите проблему в общих чертах.

- Если кто-то закрыл ваш вопрос, сосредоточьтесь на *причине закрытия вопроса*, а не на том, *почему этот участник закрыл вопрос*.
- Если вам кажется, что кто-то злоупотребляет очередью проверки, сосредоточьтесь на том, *как, по вашему мнению, следует выполнять проверку*, а не на том, *что вот этот участник вредит сайту*.
- Если Вас что-то не устраивает в учетной записи участника, сосредоточьтесь на том, *какое содержимое допустимо указывать в учетных записях в общем*, а не на том, *разрешено ли данному участнику его размещать*.

Если сообщество приходит к выводу, что упомянутое действие недопустимо, появляется необходимость устранения недостатка. Пометьте сообщение этого участника тревогой или используйте [форму обратной связи](/contact), чтобы сообщить о нежелательном поведении, сославшись на соответствующий вопрос на Мете. **Никогда** не ссылайтесь на других участников в вашем вопросе на Мете.

Даже если имя участника легко определить из контекста (например, если вы ссылаетесь на вопрос, где имя участника присутствует в явном виде), прямое упоминание в вопросе смещает акцент с реальной проблемы на участника в целом. В подобном смещении нет никакой необходимости. Оно лишь отвлекает других участников от реальной проблемы: неправильного поведения.

### Как бы вы вели себя оказавшись в подобной ситуации?

Никому не нравится публичная критика, но есть способ уменьшить стресс. Постановка вопроса в обобщённом виде побуждает сообщество обсуждать проблему нейтрально, что помогает сообществу сфокусироваться на самой проблеме и снимает стресс с участника, чьё поведение породило дискуссию.

Если вы показываете пальцем на конкретного участника, высказывая «Вы поступаете неправильно!» – это вызывает у него лишь бурные эмоции. В зависимости от характера участника, у него может произойти выброс адреналина, он может совершенно запутаться в том, что именно он сделал не так, или просто очень расстроиться. Это совершенно несправедливо в ситуации, когда участник может просто не осознавать, что он сделал что–то не так, или просто искренне пытаясь помочь, выходит за рамки правил сообщества.

Нейтральная постановка вопроса более располагает к тому, чтобы автор неверного, по вашему мнению, поведения пришёл и спокойно принял участие в обсуждении, объяснив, при необходимости, мотивы своего поведения.

### Наши рекомендации

Представленные ниже рекомендации далеко не идеальные, достаточно субъективные и подлежащие дальнейшему обсуждению.

- Если вопрос можно представить в общем виде так, чтобы в нём вовсе не упоминались участники, участникам сообщества и модераторам следует удалять любые имена и ссылки на учетные записи из вопроса, в случае прецедента.
- Если вопрос невозможно представить в общем виде, так как необходим контекст, или же удаление имени участника из вопроса не исправит ситуацию (вред уже причинён), модераторам следует немедленно удалить вопрос, оставив комментарий, рекомендующий автору отметить проблемное сообщение сигналом тревоги или воспользоваться формой обратной связи.
- Комментарии, в которых обсуждается конкретный участник или действия участника, не связанные с разбираемым в данный момент поведением, должны удаляться незамедлительно. Мета – не место для создания списков биографий и ошибок участников.

Это довольно-таки субъективное мнение, но нам хотелось бы подчеркнуть, что упоминание участников неуместно. Обсуждение конкретного участника, которое превращается в поливание грязью, *никогда* ещё не было конструктивным, и неважно, насколько цивилизованно идёт общение. Мы видели множество обсуждений, которые оставались довольно культурными на Мете, но имели плачевные последствия на основном сайте и даже вне его.

Ваша цель в постановке вопроса на Мете должна состоять в том, чтобы выяснить, какое поведение является правильным, но не исправлять поведение самостоятельно. Если ваш вопрос сможет повлиять на поведение - прекрасно, но изменение поведения одного конкретного участника не может являться конечной целью. Мы здесь не для того, чтобы стыдить кого–либо, в обратном случае, у наших коллег не будет другого выхода, кроме как покинуть сообщество.

---

### Несколько слов в завершение

Как мне кажется, последний тренд формата обсуждения конкретных участников на Мете крайне пагубно может сказаться на сообществе. При взаимодействие на основном сайте мы все делаем ошибки, которые, в общем–то, не так уж и сложно исправить. Совершенно иначе дело обстоит с взаимодействиями между людьми: обидев коллегу, случайно, не со зла, восстановить отношения может быть куда сложнее, чем «удалить неверно оставленный комментарий».

Конечно же, обсуждать ошибки модерации необходимо, но исключительно «в общем», без привязки к участнику, то есть «вот ситуация, как надо было поступить?» На мой взгляд, никогда не следует заявлять «вот Вася, он – плохой». Если вы все же хотите сделать столь резкое заявление, пожалуйста, закройте Мету, выйдите из системы чатов и возвращайтесь на следующий день. Возможно, когда эмоции уйдут, вы сможете посмотреть на ситуацию со стороны.

Обсуждение формата «какого поведения следует придерживаться в данной ситуации (контекст)» – несет пользу, так как сообщество определяет лучшие шаблоны поведения, которые становятся справкой для новичков, и в будущем, в случае появления нежелательного поведения, мы сможем ссылаться на вопрос–обсуждение на Мете. Упоминания конкретных участников, в свою очередь, – наносит обиду и разъединяет нас.

*Пожалуйста, избегайте вопросов–обсуждений конкретных участников. Ставьте вопрос в общем виде, как–будто собираетесь написать FAQ–вопрос.*

**Дополнение**

Если вы считаете, что модератор сделал что–то неверно и вы хотите обратить на это внимание, *не используйте для этого Мету, напишите об этом через [форму обратной связи](/contact) или [управляющему на почту](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99338/274323)*. Ваш вопрос будет рассмотрен детально в индивидуальном порядке.