# Допустимо ли требовать на Мете публично раскрыть детали о собственном (!) нарушении?

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, модерация, блокировка

От некоторых участников поступили заявления о том, что их заблокировали в чате за совершенно нейтральные сообщения, а присланные им лично детали содержали лишь общие формулировки и ни слова о том, какое отношение они имеют к конкретному случаю. Разумеется, утверждать можно что угодно. Но *предположим*, что некоторым из этих заявлений можно верить.

---

Я заметил на Мете как минимум один вопрос*, просьбу *публично* раскрыть причину *собственной* блокировки (т. е. блокировки самого спрашивающего) и доказательства её обоснованности.

**Этот вопрос был удалён без объяснения причин,** с рекомендацией по вопросам блокировки обратиться через личные каналы связи.

---

Можно попытаться объяснить это вопросом ["Следует ли обращаться к участникам по имени в вопросах на Мете?"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4790/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BA-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%85-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5), если бы не одна важная деталь: он про обсуждение **видимых** действий третьих лиц.

Публичное раскрытие информации о блокировке есть раскрытие **невидимых** действий администрации, поэтому большая часть рассуждений, приведённых там, совершенно *неприменима* к этой ситуации.

Есть также норма поведения для модераторов — не отвечать на вопросы о подробностях блокировки третьих лиц, ибо "захочет — сам расскажет". В этом случае не действует и она: заблокированный — автор обращения, а не какое-то там третье лицо. И к тому же он рад бы рассказать сам, но его видение ситуации расходится с видением модераторов/администрации, потому он и прибег к публичному обращению.

---

Для меня, как стороннего наблюдателя, подобные действия администрации выглядят как **замалчивание** и **подрывают доверие к администрации** — в интересах администрации исключить трактовку "вас могут забанить за что угодно и активно тереть свидетельства", которая лежит на поверхности и ничем не опровергается.

Выйдя с подобным обращением на Мету, участник соглашается вынести обсуждение своей блокировки на публику, т. к. считает, что сообщество будет на его стороне или как минимум не осудит его действия.

1. Есть ли у администрации веские причины не отвечать на такие запросы на Мете? О причинах *отвечать* прямо сказано выше. Если более весомых причин *не отвечать* нет, удалённые обращения необходимо восстановить.
2. Или, если оставлять такие запросы на Мете видится нежелательным, стоит ли удалять их уже *после* обсуждений, все стороны сделали свои выводы о справедливости блокировки и "опыт сообщества на будущее" из ситуации успешно извлечён (его можно при необходимости изложить в отдельном обезличенном вопросе)?

---

* ссылку на этот удалённый вопрос не привожу; если такие обращения будут признаны допустимыми, стоит дать авторам шанс пересмотреть свои намерения и принять решение о публикации уже в новых обстоятельствах

Comment: Личная просьба минусующим обосновывать свой минус комментарием или, лучше, ответом.

Comment: @VladD Я не минусовал, но предположу, что людям не хочется долгих и, скорей всего, неконструктивных обсуждений-выяснений с чужим "грязным нижним бельём".

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov т.е. из-за того что какой-то группе не хочется вникать в чужую проблему, вопрос стал неконструктивным? Обратите внимание - вопрос общий, а не частный. Еще вы исходите из неверной предпосылки, что раз удалено, значит за дело, а вопрос как раз о противоположном, когда есть сомнения в обоснованности принятых мер.

Comment: @GreenDragon Зачем вы додумываете, что я исхожу из какой-то "предпосылки" и всё остальное? Я же просто высказал предположение почему другие могут голосовать "против" этого вопроса, не более того. Про некоструктивность речи тоже не было.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov я имел ввиду, что не вы лично так делаете, но только те, кто считают рассмотрение общей ситуацией цитирую "долгих и, скорей всего, неконструктивных обсуждений-выяснений с чужим "грязным нижним бельём"" (т.е. это не к вам, но к вашему аргументу). Надеюсь, теперь вы меня поняли.

Answer (score 7):

Выделил основные мысли заголовками. Писал быстро, ещё могу додумать/передумать/засомневаться. Любой обратной связи рад, пишите в комментариях.

---

Чтобы узнать причины бана, необязательно кому-то их публиковать на Мете. Бан всегда сопровождается письмом от модераторов и на него можно ответить, попросить подробностей. Многие так и делают, в ответ получают детали и объяснения. В истории вижу даже несколько ответов в духе «спасибо, стало понятнее». Заскриншотить не могу, простите.

> ## Сначала спросите в письме

Когда нужно публичное обсуждение? Видимо, когда «видение ситуации расходится с видением модераторов/администрации». Ок, давайте подумаем, как обсудить.

Мне видится такой вариант решения. Забаненный явно соглашается, что подробности нарушения раскроют. Прямо пишет «я согласен, мне важней узнать подробности и разные мнения». Про чужой бан так спрашивать нельзя. Понятно, что забаненный на Мету не напишет, но может написать в письме.

> ## Спорные вопросы обсуждаем по запросу

Модератор в ответ максимально деликатно раскрывает и объясняет, в чем проблема с поведением участника. Аргументируя правилами. Вырезая все упоминания других людей. Иначе в довесок к бану получится ещё и публичная порка, а она нам не нужна.

> ## Обсуждаем действия, а не участников

Возможно, будет лучше, если ответит не только забанивший модератор, но и его коллеги, а потом и другие участники.
Но от всех нужны обоснованные и рациональные мнения. 
Эмоции и голословные заявления не нужны: они только разогреют ссору.

> ## Аргументы, а не эмоции

И наконец, возможно что обсуждение все-таки скатывается в порку или самому забаненному от него некомфортно. Считаю, что у него должно быть безусловное право на удаление такого вопроса вместе с ответами. Да, это противоречит «накоплению знания» и общим правилам, но тут исключительный случай.

> ## Удаляем обсуждение по первой просьбе забаненного

---

Важно: это не правило! От того, что модератор (я) написал этот ответ, это не стало правилом на РУ.СО. И даже если на нем будет много плюсов, это не станет правилом. А если будет много минусов, то не обяжет модератора отказать в просьбе. Человеческие отношения тут сильнее правил.

> ## Отношения сильнее правил

---

Немножко личного опыта. Когда-то на SuperUser удалили мой ответ, а я сначала модератору написал, а потом ещё и на Мету. Пост был в духе «душат свободу, гнобят начинающих участников». Потом я сам стал модератором, прошло два года. Теперь я понимаю, что мой ответ был просто плохим, а за пост на мете мне до сих пор стыдно.

Comment: Вопрос еще и блокировок в чате касается, таким можно на Мету писать. Если можно отразите в ответе что разницы нет, а если есть то в чем.

Comment: «Понятно, что забаненный на Мету не напишет, но может написать в письме.» — А если администрация игнорирует письмо? Ну там, из-за плохого админского интерфейса или ещё по какой-нибудь отмазке?

Comment: @GreenDragon ну вот в том и разница, что на Мету можно писать )))

Comment: `самому забаненному от него некомфортно` - а если вдруг ни с того, ни с сего, некомфортно становится модератору? Он тоже имеет безусловное право на удаление?

Comment: «Важно: это не правило!» — тогда хотелось бы получить от кого-то точное правило: что нам, как участникам, гарантировано?

Comment: @vp_arth цель не в том, чтобы сделать некомфортно хоть участнику, хоть модератору. Цель — понять друг друга, договориться, насколько это возможно.

Comment: @VladD я могу гарантировать, что я вас уважаю и всегда стремлюсь сотрудничать, что я с вами честен, что я постараюсь признавать свои ошибки, но и ваши не проигнорирую. Но вы же про что-то конкретное спросить хотите? Если так, скажите, какой гарантии не хватает?

Comment: @NickVolynkin: Это большая тема, и достаточно неприятная. И она оффтопик в этом вопросе. Повертье, требования формализовать наши права возникли не на пустом месте.

Comment: @NickVolynkin: Но спасибо, польщён.

Comment: Я лично не вижу смысла в каких-то формальных гарантиях, т. к. цель подобного раскрытия -- возвращение доверия к администрации. Если же есть необходимость в таких гарантиях, значит этого доверия нет по каким-то особо тяжёлым причинам и раскрытие не особенно этому поможет.

Comment: @D-side ох уж это обтекаемое слово «администрация». Скажите адресно, вы мне доверяете или нет?

Comment: @NickVolynkin лично вам -- ну, поводов сомневаться вы пока не дали. Но блокировки, я полагаю, всё же выписываются с консенсуса администрации, коллективного. Я могу верить лично вам, но допускать, что вы консенсусом можете быть недовольны, т. к. не доверяю коллективу в целом.

Comment: @D-side ок, спасибо. Блокировки выписываются чаще единолично, сегодня вроде ПашаПаш про это писал в чате. Но если есть сомнения, всегда обсуждаем постфактум. Вот эту обсуждаем.

Comment: @vp_arth с недавних пор это может быть один и тот же человек :)

Comment: Недавно видел обсужение на англ. мете про бан пользователя с высокой репой (ссылку не дам, потерялась). Тот просто написал, что не хочет обсуждать это. Модератор перенёс это в ответ.